# Libgdx Texture Size Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm having problem with scaling images ,every device has different screen resolution and i can't figure out how scale them down in the Libgdx Platform,
for example today i've made a small game for android and the problem that i am facing is..
[image]

offcurse we can scale them down ,but this is not the right way, because if someone has a tablet the Butttons will fit perfect,and in libgdx as far as i know i cant use the layouts sw600dp,large,xlarge etc ...how we can scale them depend of the screen width and height

```
stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    font = new BitmapFont();
    skin = new Skin();
    buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/Spritesheetbuttons.pack"));
    skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
    Table table = new Table();
    table.setBounds(0,0,buttonAtlas.getRegions().get(0).getRegionWidth()*2 , buttonAtlas.getRegions().get(0).getRegionHeight());

    textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("left");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("left");
    textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("left");
    buttonLeft = new TextButton("Button1", textButtonStyle);
    table.add(buttonLeft);

    textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("right");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("right");
    textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("right");
    buttonRight = new TextButton("Button1", textButtonStyle);
    table.add(buttonRight);
    stage.addActor(table);



    table = new Table();
    table.setBounds(Game.SCREEN_WIDTH-buttonAtlas.getRegions().get(0).getRegionWidth(),0,buttonAtlas.getRegions().get(0).getRegionWidth() , buttonAtlas.getRegions().get(0).getRegionHeight()*2);

    textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("up");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("up");
    textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("up");
    buttonUp = new TextButton("Button1", textButtonStyle);
    table.add(buttonUp);
    table.row();

    textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("down");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("down");
    textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("down");
    buttonDown = new TextButton("Button1", textButtonStyle);
    table.add(buttonDown);
    stage.addActor(table);


    buttonRight.addListener(new EventListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean handle(Event event) {

        }
    });
    buttonLeft.addListener(new EventListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean handle(Event event) {

        }
    });
    buttonDown.addListener(new EventListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean handle(Event event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    });
    buttonUp.addListener(new EventListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean handle(Event event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're relying on asset size and using imaginary pixel units. Have a look at [this post](http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels) why you shouldn't do that. Instead you could use [a viewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) with a more meaningful units. E.g. you could use the actual size of the screen (e.g. in inches or centimeters) for your viewport and then specify the size of the button (again in inches or centimeters) that you want them to be. You might also want/need to call the `Drawable#setMinWidth()`, depending on your skin.

```
float widthInches = (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * Gdx.graphics.getPpiX();
float heightInches = (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * Gdx.graphics.getPpiY();
stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(widthInches, heightInches));
...
// e.g. if you want your buttons to be 1 by 1 inch 
button.setSize(1f, 1f);
button.getStyle().up.setMinWidth(1f);
button.getStyle().up.setMinHeight(1f);
... etc. for the other drawables your button uses
```

Comment: thnks for your answer it was very helpfull, but i have one problem..i have screen width,height 100 meter and VIEWPORT_WIDTH,VIEWPORT_HEIGHT 30 meter and i want no matter what the screen size device is to let the user to see only that specific viewport not more not less.. so far we are good but after the scale all the OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer will deformed.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use another viewport. In this answer I use the actual screen size, so it will have the correct aspect ratio. If you need a different aspect ratio then you need to decide how to deal with that difference. This one stretches, while others use various techniques to maintain aspect ratio. Check the link in the answer.